# Htlatex and chapters/sections malfunction

Tags: htlatex

When using `htlatex` on the file with `\chapter{...}` etc., the resulting html file loses paragraph formatting and is all one big paragraph.

When I comment out `\chapter` etc., all works fine. I use `memoir` class.

`htlatex Test_html.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8" "" "--shell-escape"`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,latin,english,german,french,dutch,italian,spanish,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\section{Section one}

Lorem ipsum

\section{Section two}

Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

Comment: could you post a minimal working example that illustrates this behavior? I cannot reproduce that with up-to date `tex4ht` distribution

Comment: which TeX distribution do you use? it works correctly on TL 2018 for me.